# boost regex - how to match an even number of digits from a range

Tags: regex, boost-regex

I would like to match an even number of digits from a range. Here is a regex which match a number of digits from range:

```
boost::regex expr("[0-9]{2,20}");
```

How to modify that regex to match an even number of digits from a range ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern `[0-9]{2,20}` repeats a digit 0-9 from 2 - 20 times.

You could use an anchor to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string and repeat matching 2 digits between 1-10 times:

```
^(?:[0-9]{2}){1,10}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H2WvEh/1)